# Cannot access a .resw string resource in WinRT that uses a property dot notation through code?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is it possible to access a string resource defined in a .resw in WinRT that uses a property dot notation?  I know how to assign the value to a XAML control through the use of the x:Uid property but I also need to access it through code.

If I define:
[image]
For "Farewell" the following works as str is "Hello".

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var str = loader.GetString("Farewell");
```

For "Greeting.Text" str equals null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it by replacing dot with slash.

For example:

```
var str = loader.GetString("Greeting/Text");
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, where did you find that? Docs?

Comment: I was struggling with the same thing a while back. Can't remember if I found the answer here or from some other site with Google, but not from the docs anyway :)